# How to select rows from a file based on conditions of another file?

Tags: linux, awk, bioinformatics

I have 2 genetic datasets, both have a column for chromosome position. I am trying to filter file 1 based on each line's chromosome position in comparison to the chromosome positions in file 2. The condition for file 1 line extraction is that only lines that have a chromosome position either more than 5000 larger or less than 5000 smaller than any given chromosome position in all the lines of file 2 is selected. Ultimately I am trying to make sure those genetic variants I extract from file 1 have a greater than 5000 +/- distance than those in file 2.

For example my data looks like:

File 1:

```
Variant   Chromosome Position
Variant1    14000
Variant2    9000
Variant3    37000
Variant4    21000
```

File 2:

```
Variant   Chromosome Position
Variant1    10000
Variant2    20000
Variant3    30000
```

Expected output (of variants with a greater than 5000 position distance in comparison to each line of file 2):

```
Variant   Chromosome Position
Variant3    37000
```

I've found questions extracting data from 2 files, but depending on matching or unqiue. I haven't yet found something applying +/- conditions to solve my question and I'm not sure where else to look/learn. I'm new to linux so I've been trying to construct a command which would have the effect of:

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR==1{print;next} {if($2>=+5000 | $2<=-5000) print $0}' file1 file2 > newfile`

but I'm unsure of the syntax to get this working - any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Will there be holes between "ranges" (e.g. `Var1 9000` & `Var2 21000` -> gap `14001 - 15999`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try also (taking "holes" between ranges into consideration)

```
$ awk '
NR == FNR       {RGMIN[++IX] = $2 - 5000                        # from file2, create min and
                 RGMAX[IX]   = $2 + 5000                        # max range boundaries
                 next
                }
FNR == 1        {print                                          # print file1 header; don't process line further
                 next
                }
                {PR = 1                                         # set PRintout logical variable

                 for (i=2; i<=IX; i++)  PR = PR * ($2 < RGMIN[i] || $2 > RGMAX[i])

                                                                # reset PR to 0 if $2 inside any of the
                                                                # ranges; skip file2's header by starting
                                                                # loop at IX 2

                }
PR                                                              # print if outside ALL ranges
' file2 file1
Variant   Chromosome Position
Variant3    37000
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this seems to have worked. Do you know any resource where I can learn about the functions you've used like ```RGMIN``` and ```RGMAX```? I googled for them but can't find any resources

Comment: Those two are locally defined array variables: Range min / max boundaries.